# I am trying to log an audit table in SQL using MVC C# to track edits using the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So far I can save my edits from the Transaction table to the TransEdit table adding my TransEdit "Entity?", but cannot get the original value before it has been changed in the edit View form.

I'm not well versed with MVC so I'm not sure how to proceed.  I am very lost. Any help is appreciated.

Currently my controller looks like this

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

namespace WaterProject2.Models
    
{
    public class TransactionsController : Controller
    {
        private omerDataEntities db = new omerDataEntities();

        // GET: Transactions
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            
            return View(db.Transactions.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Transactions/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Transaction transaction = db.Transactions.Find(id);
            if (transaction == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(transaction);
        }

        // GET: Transactions/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {

            ViewBag.ReferenceIDs = new SelectList(db.Transactions, "Ref_ID","Ref_ID");
            ViewBag.CompanyDroplist = new SelectList(db.Entities, "Entities","Entities");
            ViewBag.CustomerDroplist = new SelectList(db.Transactions, "Customer", "Customer");
            ViewBag.AssetDroplist = new SelectList(db.Assets, "Asset_Name", "Asset_Name");
            ViewBag.DealsDroplist = new SelectList(db.deals, "Ref_ID", "Ref_ID");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Transactions/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Trans_Nbr,Ref_ID,TransDT,Company,Deal,Status,Trans_Lead,Customer,Vendor,Transaction_Type,Water_Type,Contract_AF,Gross_AF,Leave_Behind_AF,AF_Value,Location_IOU,Notes,Invoice_Nbr,Contract_Dt,Instructions,OTN,Asset_Nbr,Asset_Name,Asset_Type,Sub_Entity,Asset_Status")] Transaction transaction)
        {
            
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Transactions.Add(transaction);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            

            return View(transaction);
        }

        // GET: Transactions/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        
                   
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            
            Transaction transaction = db.Transactions.Find(id);
            

            if (transaction == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            


            return View(transaction);
        }
        
        // POST: Transactions/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Trans_Nbr,Ref_ID,TransDT,Company,Deal,Status,Trans_Lead,Customer,Vendor,Transaction_Type,Water_Type,Contract_AF,Gross_AF,Leave_Behind_AF,AF_Value,Location_IOU,Notes,Invoice_Nbr,Contract_Dt,Instructions,OTN,Asset_Nbr,Asset_Name,Asset_Type,Sub_Entity,Asset_Status")] Transaction transaction)
        {

           Transaction origTrans = db.Transactions.Find(transaction.Trans_Nbr);
            TransEdit newTransEdit = new TransEdit();
            newTransEdit.Trans_Nbr = origTrans.Trans_Nbr + 10;
            newTransEdit.Ref_ID = origTrans.Ref_ID;
            newTransEdit.TransDT = origTrans.TransDT;
            newTransEdit.Company = origTrans.Company;
            newTransEdit.Deal = origTrans.Deal;
            newTransEdit.Status = origTrans.Status;
            newTransEdit.Trans_Lead = origTrans.Trans_Lead;
            newTransEdit.Customer = origTrans.Customer;
            newTransEdit.Vendor = origTrans.Vendor;
            newTransEdit.Transaction_Type = origTrans.Transaction_Type;
            newTransEdit.Water_Type = origTrans.Water_Type;
            newTransEdit.Contract_AF = origTrans.Contract_AF;
            newTransEdit.Gross_AF = origTrans.Gross_AF;
            newTransEdit.Leave_Behind_AF = origTrans.Leave_Behind_AF;
            newTransEdit.AF_Value = origTrans.AF_Value;
            newTransEdit.Location_IOU = origTrans.Location_IOU;
            newTransEdit.Notes = origTrans.Notes;
            newTransEdit.Invoice_Nbr = origTrans.Invoice_Nbr;
            newTransEdit.Contract_Dt = origTrans.Contract_Dt;
            newTransEdit.Instructions = origTrans.Instructions;
            newTransEdit.OTN = origTrans.OTN;
            newTransEdit.Asset_Nbr = origTrans.Asset_Nbr;
            newTransEdit.Asset_Name = origTrans.Asset_Name;
            newTransEdit.Asset_Type = origTrans.Asset_Type;
            newTransEdit.Sub_Entity = origTrans.Sub_Entity;
            newTransEdit.Asset_Status = origTrans.Asset_Status;
                       
            db.Entry(newTransEdit).State = EntityState.Added;
            db.SaveChanges();
            

            
          
            
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
              
                db.Set<Transaction>().AddOrUpdate(transaction);
                db.SaveChanges();
                
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(transaction);
        }

        // GET: Transactions/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Transaction transaction = db.Transactions.Find(id);
            if (transaction == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(transaction);
        }

        // POST: Transactions/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Transaction transaction = db.Transactions.Find(id);
            db.Transactions.Remove(transaction);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        public ActionResult SearchIndex(string searchString)
        {
            
            var TransSearch = from m in db.Transactions
                         select m;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                TransSearch = TransSearch.Where(s => s.Ref_ID.Contains(searchString)); 
                    
                    
                
            }

            return View(TransSearch);
        }
      
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

My Model

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace WaterProject2.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class Transaction
    {
        public int Trans_Nbr { get; set; }
        public string Ref_ID { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime TransDT { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public string Deal { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
        public string Trans_Lead { get; set; }
        public string Customer { get; set; }
        public string Vendor { get; set; }
        public string Transaction_Type { get; set; }
        public string Water_Type { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Contract_AF { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Gross_AF { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Leave_Behind_AF { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> AF_Value { get; set; }
        public string Location_IOU { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public string Invoice_Nbr { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Contract_Dt { get; set; }
        public string Instructions { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> OTN { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Asset_Nbr { get; set; }
        public string Asset_Name { get; set; }
        public string Asset_Type { get; set; }
        public string Sub_Entity { get; set; }
        public string Asset_Status { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and my view

```
@model WaterProject2.Models.Transaction

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Transaction</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Trans_Nbr)

    <div class="form-group">
       @* @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ref_ID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
        <div class="col-md-10">
            
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Ref_ID)
            @* @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ref_ID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
            @* @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ref_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TransDT, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TransDT, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TransDT, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Company, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Company, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Company, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Deal, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Deal, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Deal, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Status, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Status, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Trans_Lead, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Trans_Lead, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Trans_Lead, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customer, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customer, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customer, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Vendor, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Vendor, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Vendor, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Transaction_Type, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Transaction_Type, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Transaction_Type, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Water_Type, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Water_Type, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Water_Type, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contract_AF, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contract_AF, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contract_AF, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gross_AF, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Gross_AF, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gross_AF, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Leave_Behind_AF, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Leave_Behind_AF, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Leave_Behind_AF, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AF_Value, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AF_Value, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AF_Value, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Location_IOU, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Location_IOU, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location_IOU, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Notes, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Notes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Notes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Invoice_Nbr, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Invoice_Nbr, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Invoice_Nbr, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contract_Dt, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contract_Dt, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contract_Dt, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Instructions, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Instructions, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Instructions, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OTN, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OTN, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OTN, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Asset_Nbr, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Asset_Nbr, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Asset_Nbr, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Asset_Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Asset_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Asset_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Asset_Type, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Asset_Type, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Asset_Type, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sub_Entity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sub_Entity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sub_Entity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Asset_Status, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Asset_Status, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Asset_Status, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the controller. This has been Solved.